# Align div inside ion-col to bottom of column

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a column with multiple `divs` inside it. How can I align the last div to the bottom of the column?

Example code:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <div> some text at the top </div>
        <div> more text at the top </div>
        <div> text at the bottom </div> <!-- I want this to be at the bottom of the column-->
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

Comment: Last div is at the bottom of the column already, it automatically places divs veritcally.

Comment: @theriddle2 there is space after the column until the next row. i want the last div to be aligned to the bottom of the column

Comment: Do you mean the padding? ion-col has a 5px padding on all sides, if you mean that then ion-col { padding: 0px } would eliminate that

Comment: @theriddle2 no sorry I didn't explain it well. I have 2 columns in an ion row. One of the columns is longer than this one, so it creates extra space.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't explain my question that well.
I had 2 columns with different heights in the same `ion-row` which was creating extra space on the shorter column.

I solved my issue by putting the desired bottom divs in a separate ion-row.